# How can I store shoes in small spaces?

Tags: shoes

My friend just moved to a new apartment and the storage spaces for his clothes (cabinets, etc.) seem small and can only fit small things. He wants to know if there is a way to store his shoes (a lot) in an organized manner. Should he just buy a shoe organizer, or is there an easier and "expense-less" solution?

Comment: How small things are small things? I think most people could argue that shoes are generally quite small as things go.

Answer (score 6):

Try a closet rod hanging shoe organizer like this:

[image: Hanging Shoe Organizer]

I've tried a few approaches, including some elaborate shoe trees.  Hanging shoe organizers are inexpensive and the most compact and clutter-free solution I have found.  Easy to move around as well.

Answer (score 5):

One of the most compact ways to store shoes (that I have found through packing suitcases) is to 'stack' the pairs so the soles of the shoes are both pointing outwards and the tongue and foot hole are inwards but at opposite ends - much like they come in a shoe box when you purchase them. See image below.
[image]
This way you can lay them down if the height of cabinets is an issue, or slot them down narrow spaces. Keep them together with string / rubber bands or even with the shoe laces.